# Can anyone explain or refer a link to me how to install Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am new to Couchbase database can anyone please guide me to how to install this software and refer some documents, so that I can understand the basics of this Database.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a tutorial on how to install Couchbase Server on Windows:

http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/may/couchbase-with-windows-and-.net---part-1

But for the record, installing it is pretty easy: just download the binary and follow instructions: http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads

Couchbase.com has a lot of material on how to use and understand Couchbase Server. Maybe you can start on the Getting Started page: http://www.couchbase.com/get-started-developing-nosql

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I understand your comment and downvote, but in this case, I don't think there's really much else to say other than: download at link and follow the instructions. Double click the binary and hit 'next' a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a newer possibility, if you are on Windows. You can use Chocolatey NuGet (which is like apt-get for Windows)

`choco install couchbase-server-community` installs 4.0.0 (as of today)

`choco install couchbase-server-community -pre` install 4.5.0 beta (as of today)

Check out [Chocolatey NuGet](https://chocolatey.org/packages/couchbase-server-community/4.0.0) for the most up to date information on which versions you can install.